# Dismiss a DialogFragment (support libraries) while activity is on background gets IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-fragments, dismiss, illegalstateexception, android-dialogfragment

In an activity of my app I need to show a "Loading" uncancelable FragmentDialog while something is uploading. I show this dialog from a callback in my current Activity like this:

```
final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
final Fragment prev = fm.findFragmentByTag( "loading" );
if ( prev != null ) {
    ft.remove(prev);
}
ft.addToBackStack(null);
final DialogFragment df = 
        IndeterminateProgressDialogFragment.newInstance(
        getString( R.string.loading_dialog_sending_data ) );
df.setCancelable( false );
df.show( ft, "loading" );
```

The upload is happening in a retained Fragment (using asynctask) that is executed from my ui Fragment. When the upload is done, my ui Fragment is informed on onActivityResult and currently it tries to dismiss the dialog. In the past it delegates the responsability of dismissing the loading dialog with a callback done on onActivityResult, but it doesn't work too.

I can dismiss this dialog while my activity is on foreground, but when is on background I get an IllegalStateException: can not perform this action after onSaveInstaneState. I tried using onRemove and this does not make my app crash but also does not hide the DialogFragment. I've done both things on my ui Fragment and my activity and the still got the problem.

I have been reading the docs but I can´t find some method I can use.

Is DialogFragment not supposed to be used like I need or what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I just managed to solve this with a dirty workaround:

I catch the IllegalStateException and set a flag to true, so when my Fragment comes back I know I tried to dismiss.

```
//All this code is inside my ui Fragment
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    final boolean kill = getArguments().getBoolean(ARG_KILL_LOADING, false);
    if ( kill ) {
        final DialogFragment df = ( DialogFragment )
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag( "loading" );
        if ( df != null ) {
            df.dismiss();
        }
    }
}


//Here I got workerfragment result and try to dismiss my DialogFragment
@Override
public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data ) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    try {
        final DialogFragment df = ( DialogFragment ) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag( "loading" );
        if ( df != null ) {
            df.dismiss(); //Let's throw an IllegalStateException if on background!
        }
    } catch( IllegalStateException ex ) {
        //dirty way to avoid crashing while on background:
        //we will ask our ui fragment to dismiss df when ui fragment comes back onResume
        getArguments().putBoolean(ARG_KILL_LOADING, true);
    }

//Do something on ui with workerfragment result

}
```

But I'm still wondering what is the right way to dismiss a FragmentDialog while onBackground. I got another project with the same problem :/

Answer (score 2):

You don't need dismiss fragment in onActivityResult and catch exception.

Just set you flag in onActivityResult. I use static variable.

```
    public class MyFragment extends DialogFragment {
            private static boolean KILL_FLAG = false;

            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                KILL_FLAG = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent data) {
                    KILL_FLAG = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onResume() {
                super.onResume();

                if(KILL_FLAG){
                    dismiss();
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: But then my fragment dialog should be the target of my retained fragment (the one doing the job on background) and my dialog will pass the results to my ui fragment. Am I right?

Comment: Do you do this only for show wait\loading dialog? Why do you use onActivityResult? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I do. With onActivityResult I get the result from my worker fragment, so I can know if the upload was succesful.